# Escape special characters in XQuery or XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xquery, osb

I have an xml that has uname and pwd. The pwd has special characters like ‘&’.

I am using a XQuery or XSLT to transform it.. the output generated should have exact password and not `&amp;`.

Is there a way I can do that?

```
<uname>xyz</uname>
<pwd>12a&ad&12</pwd>
```

Output after transformation should exactly same

(I am doing this in OSB, so when I test through OSB it doesn't allow me to, so I am using SoapUI to validate ut, but at the first stage itself it fails to handle it)

Can someone please guide me with the escaping special characters or XQuery or XSLT functions for this

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

XQuery and XSLT are both designed for processing well-formed XML, and your input is not well-formed XML, so it cannot be processed using these languages. To make it well-formed XML, it needs to be written

```
<data>
  <uname>xyz</uname>
  <pwd>12a&amp;ad&amp;12</pwd>
</data>
```

Similarly, the output will always be well-formed XML.

Comment: In the request i can use &amp; .. but since its a password the ouput has to be & and not &amp;the call goes to rest api at the backend and it needs the exact pwd

Comment: If the rest API is expecting XML, then it's expecting `&` to be represented as `&amp;`. If it's expecting something other than XML, then it would be best to avoid using XML-like tag syntax.

Comment: Thanks Michael. 
But in general is there any xslt or xquery to escape special characters

Comment: Any tool that creates XML (XSLT, XQuery, DOM, Linq etc) will escape special characters when you serialise the constructed XML tree.